# How do I syntax check a Zsh script?

Tags: shell-script, zsh, syntax

I can do it in bash using `bash -n script.sh` command.
is this possible in zsh?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is it's the same `-n`/`-o noexec` as in POSIX shells, that causes the code to be read and parsed but not executed.

See `info zsh noexec` for details.

Beware it flags shell syntax errors, but not necessarily things like wildcard/qualifier/expansion flag syntax errors.

Also note that some options affect the syntax of the shell. So if you have some `set -o those-options`, since it will not be executed, `zsh -n` will carry on trying to interpret the syntax as if it hadn't been enabled.

Comment: Note `zsh -n` doesn't detect many syntax errors.